# How do I get Google Docs/atachment URL from a Google Calendar event?

Tags: javascript, scripting, google-calendar-api

I have this Google Scripts script:

```
function moveHangoutLinks() {
    var calendarId = 'fzivolo@quid.com';
    var now = new Date();
    var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
        timeMin: now.toISOString(),
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime',
        maxResults: 10
    });
    if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
            var event = events.items[i];
            var d = event.description;
            if (!d)
                d = '';
            if (event.googleDocsLink && (d.indexOf('Hangout: ') == -1)) {
                // Logger.log (event.summary + ' - ' + event.hangoutLink + ' - ' + event.description);
                event.description = 'Hangout: ' + event.hangoutLink + '\n\n' + d;
                Calendar.Events.update(event, calendarId, event.id);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Logger.log('No events found.');
    }
}
```

It basically takes the Hangout Link of each event on Google Calendars and puts it in the event description.

I would like to do the same with any Google Docs attachments, but I can't find any documentation to know which properties are available inside the `event` object.

How can I do/where can I find the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

A successful HTTP request,

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events
```

will return [events resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) in response body with the following structure:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#events",
  "items": [
    "attachments": [
    {
      "fileUrl": string,
      "title": string,
      "mimeType": string,
      "iconLink": string,
      "fileId": string
    }
    ]
  ]
}
```

wherein `attachments[].fileUrl` is the URL link to the attachment. For adding Google Drive file attachments use the same format as in `alternateLink` property of the Files resource in the Drive API.

Comment: Thank you! Do you see anything wrong here? It doesn't seem to add the docs URL in the description for some reason.

Comment: Try updating your events using [`Events: update`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) with parameter `supportsAttachments` set to `true`.

Comment: I don't find how to use the google scripts API to enable this flag, btw I don't get how this flag could be needed. The data is already fetched when I run the "update" command...